# How to enter a variable into a function in Vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

```
<div class="content col-xs-12 cols-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" v-for="content in contents">
      <div class="content-box animated slideInUp" :style="{ '-webkit-animation-delay': content * 0.2 + 's' }">
          <div class="box-img">
            <div class="content-type">gamemode</div>
          </div>
          <h1 class="content-box-title">
            {{ content.title }}
          </h1>
          <div class="content-description">
            <p>{{ content.message }}</p>
          </div>
          <a href="http://pro-pawn.ru/showthread.php?15165-Geebrox&p=84108&viewfull=1#post84108" class="content-button" :class="{ animated: bounce, pulse: bounce }" @mouseOver="{ bounce = true }" @mouseLeave="{ bounce = false }">Перейти</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have this code, and how to increase `content` variable in `contents`. I want to get 1 then 2 then 3 and so on. Then I will multiply that value by 0.2 to get animation delay. But it isn't working.

```
:style="{ '-webkit-animation-delay': content * 0.2 + 's' }"
```

Vue script:

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  data: {
    bounce: false,
    contents: [
      { title: 'title first', message: 'message first' },
      { title: 'title second', message: 'message second' },
      { title: 'title third', message: 'message third' }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi! Can you elaborate on _"But it isn't working"_? What happens, or doesn't happen? Console errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v-for="(content, index) in contents"
```

and then

```
:style="{ '-webkit-animation-delay': (index+1) * 0.2 + 's' }"
```

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for

Check 2nd example